# Configuring permissions for JNLP:

Tags: java, permissions, jnlp, java-web-start

I'm trying to run a webstart demo, which ran on my friend's Windows machine, but throws an access error on my Ubuntu Linux box.

```
javaws http://common.l2fprod.com/jnlp/demo.jnlp
```

And I get the following error on my Linux box:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission javawebstart.version read)
```

I assume this is a configuration issue on my Ubuntu machine.  What needs to be changed to allow access to the webstart version?

Comment: Why do you need access to that information in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

The default Java installation is different from the one you download explicitly on a Windows machine

Change the default to the Sun Java 6 JDK with

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

and try again. For Ubuntu 10.4, first enable the appropriate repository with

```
add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
```

([Canonical release note][1] - note link breaks in StackOverflow, copy manually)

[1]: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx/ReleaseNotes#Sun Java moved to the Partner repository

Comment: That isn't available on my distribution.  I'm on the newest one and only java-6-openjdk is available.

Comment: Use `add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"` and try again.  For details see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx/ReleaseNotes#Sun Java moved to the Partner repository

Comment: sun/oracle java is not recommended anymore unfortunately, I think it works now with openjdk "OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10.1)"